# BLToolkit - Current readiness for Azure

Tags: bltoolkit

Does anybody know if BLToolkit has been tested and certified for use with Azure Sql and if it supports the dropped connection retry functionality? And if not are there any plans to get it tested and passed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At  the time of writing, there is nothing official on the [BL Toolkit website](http://bltoolkit.net/default.aspx?AspxAutoDetectCookieSupport=1), and no issues listed in their [issue tracker](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues) for Azure.

There are a few other requests (e.g. [here](http://groups.google.com/group/bltoolkit/browse_thread/thread/5092236d7472085a) and [here](http://groups.google.com/group/bltoolkit/browse_thread/thread/e210cc998130060b)) that are requesting the same details. At the moment they are unanswered but you could add your weight to them.

Based on this evidence from the official sources I would say that the Toolkit is not Tested or Certified *specifically* for Azure use.

With the exception of the [transient nature of Azure](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/appfabriccat/archive/2010/10/28/best-practices-for-handling-transient-conditions-in-sql-azure-client-applications.aspx) which may require handling of database reconnections, there doesn't seem to be anything obvious that would prevent you from using the Toolkit however.

I would recommend you [raise an issue](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/issues) with the developers regarding Azure Testing and Certification while performing a proof of concept test on Azure to determine how to best handle reconnections on Azure for your specific application.

There is [recent activity on the project](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit), so I'd be quite hopeful of a response.

Comment: In which case I think you've found your answer :)

Comment: I was hoping to attract IT who would provide a definitive answer.

Comment: Lack of confirmation/certification on the official websites is pretty definitive. The only means to be more definitive is to contact the developers as recommended.

Comment: Hi Kynth, I think the @IT dude, is the local Bltoolkit support rep here on stack. Thanks for making an effort.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote Azure Sql Data Provider for BLToolkit. You can find its [sources on github](https://github.com/krabishe/BLToolkit.AzureSql).
Also it's available over NuGet. Please, see how to install and configure it [here](https://github.com/krabishe/BLToolkit.AzureSql#bltoolkitazuresql).